# How do I return the error?

Tags: apache-flex, zend-framework, flash-builder

I have an app with 4 different php service calls. They work fine on localhost and remotehost. I tried to add a 5th php service call ("myservice") to my app. When I did that, the app worked fine on localhost but I came across the following error message when I tried the app on my remotehost:

```
code:
0

Message:
Class "myservice" does not exist: Plugin by name 'Myservice' was not found in the registry; used paths:
: /path/to/my/directory/

Detail:
#0 /path/to/my/directory/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Amf/Server.php(550): Zend_Amf_Server->_dispatch('getPaged', Array, 'myservice')
#1 /path/to/my/directory/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Amf/Server.php(626): Zend_Amf_Server->_handle(Object(Zend_Amf_Request_Http))
#2 /path/to/my/directory/bin-debug/gateway.php(69): Zend_Amf_Server->handle()
#3 {main}
```

I have zend installed on localhost and remotehost but can't figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
ArneRie, you are right. I got it working. thx!

Comment: Looks like localhost -> windows? Check filenames (case sensetiv on linux)

Comment: if you put your comment in the form of an answer I'll accept it because it definitely got me on the right track and saved me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check correct naming of your Files and Folders on your server.

```
/My/Model/Xyz.php != /my/model/xyz.php
```